# DialogFragment buttons not visible on few device configurations

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-databinding

I am trying to implement DialogFragment but when ever i show the dialog positive and negative buttons are not visible on some device configurations.

> **buttons visible on tablet portrait mode**

[image: buttons visible on tablet portrait mode]

> **buttons invisible on tablet landscape mode**

[image: buttons invisible on tablet landscape mode]

here is my DialogFragment code

```
class UsersDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: AddUsersDialogBinding

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val builder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext()).setTitle("Add Users")
            .setMessage("Specify details regarding new user")
            .setPositiveButton("Save") { _, _ ->
                Timber.d("clicked save button")
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
                Timber.d("cancelling save action")
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.add_users_dialog, null, false)
        return builder.setView(binding.root).create()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        dialog!!.setCancelable(false)
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

activity code where this dialog is shown

```
            val dialogFragment = UsersDialogFragment()
            dialogFragment.show(fragmentTransaction, "dialog")
```

Edit: layout file

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
                    ............
                    ............
                    ............
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: consider the current layout inside a `ScrollView` and/or for different layouts of different screen orientations / widths i.e. input fields 2 by n instead of of 1 by n - these would go into folders like `layout-land`, `layout-swXXXdp`, `layout-land-swXXXdp` etc

Comment: @MarkKeen layout is already within ScrollView. i have just uploaded tablet config but on a phone buttons are not even visible in any config.

Comment: put your various editviews inside the, scroll view and the buttons outside at the bottom .

Comment: @Kaveri no buttons are present within my layout file those buttons are just from Dialog popup.

Comment: Can you please add your dialog layout.